# How can I limit the amount of food being produced in my model according to a specific distribution

Tags: netlogo

In my model I produce food across the environment. I know how much food in total there should be and I'm packaging it up according to a specific distribution, a Gamma in this case.

Most of the food decays at the end of the day whereupon I want to start the process again for the next day. (I do have some food agents that take longer to decay but that shouldn't affect what I'm looking for here).

I want something like the following but can't quite get it:

```
  if ticks = 0 [while [sum [mass] of foods < 100000] [
create-foods n-foods [ ;; this could be arbitrarily high to allow the model to keep making food up to the limit of the mass
set mass random-gamma 1.2 0.002
]]]
```

For completeness, later on I ask the food agents to increment a decay counter and I use this to tell them whether or not to die at the end of the day:

```
  ask foods with [decay = 2] [die]
```

Hope you can help

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. What's your question about it? How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: The total food mass invariably goes way above the limit I set for mas (100000)

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the code you've shown us.

Comment: I got it going by having patches sprout the food agents (see the response to my own question). Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me by using patches to sprout the food items.

```
ask patches [
    while [sum [mass] of foods < random-normal 6000 100] [
sprout-foods 1 [ 
set mass random-gamma 1.2 0.004
setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
]]
```